# How to correctly specify timeout in ThreadPoolExecutor (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have the following code where I am trying to call functions with different timeouts. It might happen that the first function times out but the second one could have been executed in the specified time.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def test1(a, b, c):
    time.sleep(5)
    d=a+b+c
    print(d)

def test2(a, b):
    time.sleep(5)
    d=a+b
    print(d)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor1:
    try:
        executor1.submit(test1, 1,2,3).result(timeout=1)
    except:
        executor1.shutdown(wait=False)
        print("Pass")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor2:
    try:
        executor2.submit(test2, 1,2).result(timeout=8)
    except:
        executor2.shutdown(wait=False)
        print("Pass-2")
```

**Expected Output**

```
Pass
3
```

**Actual Output**

```
Pass
6
3
```

What I'd like to have is stop the execution of first `executor` as soon as there is a `timeout`. And continue with the next `executor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is implemented using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631315/python-properly-kill-exit-futures-thread). The final code is shared below :-

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import ctypes

def terminate_thread(thread):
    """Terminates a python thread from another thread.

    :param thread: a threading.Thread instance
    """
    if not thread.isAlive():
        return

    exc = ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
        ctypes.c_long(thread.ident), exc)
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("nonexistent thread id")
    elif res > 1:
        # """if it returns a number greater than one, you're in trouble,
        # and you should call it again with exc=NULL to revert the effect"""
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread.ident, None)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")

def test1(a, b, c):
    time.sleep(5)
    d=a+b+c
    print(d)

def test2(a, b):
    time.sleep(5)
    d=a+b
    print(d)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    try:
        executor.submit(test1, 1,2,3).result(timeout=1)
    except:
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)
        for t in executor._threads:
            terminate_thread(t)
        print("Pass")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    try:
        executor.submit(test2, 1,2).result(timeout=8)
    except:
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)
        for t in executor._threads:
            terminate_thread(t)
        print("Pass-2")
```